# Get filenames of 3 nested PHP scripts one inside another

Tags: php, variables, syntax

Grandparent is a file called "grandparent.php" with contents:

```
include('parent.php');
```

Parent is a file called "parent.php" with contents:

```
include('child.php');
```

Child is a file called "child.php" with contents:

```
echo "My Grandparent is at: " . $_SERVER['SCRIPT_FILENAME'] . "<br>";
echo "My Parent is at: " . $_SERVER['where_is_my_parent'] . "<br>";
echo "I'm at: " .  __FILE__;
```

So, where is the one level up parent script ($_SERVER['where_is_my_parent']) in this scenario?

Comment: debug_print_backtrace

Comment: Yes, it lists the included files that are nested one in another and it looks good, thanks! When used with: echo "<pre>"; debug_print_backtrace(); echo "</pre>"; However, it would be great if there were a $_SERVER like variable or maybe there is a function to get only the path/filename as array or string